# Why output of my BST-validating function is false?

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I wrote a function to populate a BST and another one to verify a given tree is a valid BST.

I could not understand why my `check` function returns false, since I have created the input as a BST.

When I pass a tree through my `check` function it checks four things:

1. First it checks that if the data in the left child is smaller than the data in the present child;
2. It checks that data in the right side is greater than the data in the present child;
3. Then it passes the address of left child as the root for the next operation where it will do same for the left child (now passed as root): here it will again check if the root (now root, previously left child) has a left child that is smaller than the present node and the right side greater similarly.
4. We pass the right side address as node, so that we can check if it's left side is smaller and the right side is bigger.

...and after all these operations return, we get `true` (if valid) else `false`.

It should return me `true`, however the output is `false` and I could not understand why?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct tree{
    int data;
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
};

struct tree* push(int d,struct tree*head1) {
    if(head1==NULL){
        head1=(struct tree*) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
        head1->data=d;
        head1->left=head1->right=NULL;
        return head1;
    }
    else if(head1->data>d){;
        head1->right=push(d,head1->right);
    }
    else{
        head1->left=push(d,head1->left);
    }
    return head1;
}

bool small(struct tree* a,int b){
    if(a==NULL){return true;}
    if(a->data<b){return true;}
    else {return false;}
}

bool large(struct tree* a,int b){
    if(a==NULL){return true;}
    if(a->data>b ){return true;}
    else {return false;}
}

bool check(struct tree*head ){
    if(head==NULL){
        printf("empty\n");
        return true;
    }
    printf("2");
    if(small(head->left,head->data)&& large(head->right,head->data) && check(head->left) && check(head->right)){
        printf("true");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        printf("false\n");
        return false;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct tree*head;
    head=push(3,head);
    head=push(10,head);
    head=push(5,head);
    check(head);
    // printf("%d",head->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: when you run it through a debugger, which line doesn't match your expectation ?

Comment: @AhmedAEK i am unable to understamd where the undesired output is being returned

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings. There are two undefined functions, and very bad is `head = push(3, head);` where `head` has not been initialised. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane i have compiler warning on the code long so i removed unnecessary functions but however these snippet remained that i have  cleared no. please take a look now also i have initialised head later in the function PUSH

Comment: Thanks for the edit, which leaves `head = push(3, head);` operating with an uninitialised variable. Did you mean to put `struct tree *head = NULL;`?

Comment: yes i ahve edited that

Comment: Now it's become even more unclear what your original code was – rolled back. Please don't make live corrections to the code that is causing the problem. It's no use in `push()` checking `if(head1 == NULL)` because the caller did not initialise it to any value.

Comment: now i have edited so have look please

Comment: Sorry, this site isn't a running dialogue as you change the code. If you do that it can become impossible to see what the original question was.

Comment: ok not editing any furthur now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the missing initialisation of `head`, the main cause for the problem mentioned in your question is in your `push` function:

- It goes into the wrong side for the recursive call. The comparison with `d` should be the opposite:

  ```
       else if(head1->data < d){  // Fix comparison
  ```

But there is also a mistake that we can even see in the description of your algorithm: to verify a BST you should not only verify that the left child's data is less, and the right child's data is more. You should verify that *all* nodes in the left side subtree have values that are less, and *all* nodes in the right side subtree have values that are more.

This you have not implemented, and so you will get false positives, like for this tree, which is not a BST:

```
             5
           /
          1
            \
             10
```

Here is one way to do it correctly:

```
#include <limits.h>

// Helper function: arguments define a "window" for the (sub)tree
bool checkWindow(struct tree*head, int low, int high) {
    return head == NULL 
           || low <= head->data  && head->data <= high
               && checkWindow(head->left, low, head->data)
               && checkWindow(head->right, head->data, high);
}

bool check(struct tree*head ){
    return checkWindow(head, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
}
```

Comment: thank you oi have been confused by this for some time thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

In function `main()` you have

```
struct tree*head;
head=push(3,head);
```

but the compiler objects to you passing an uninitialised variable.

In the `push()` function you have

```
if(head1==NULL)
```

but that is useless, since the value of `head1` is indeterminate. in `main()` you should have

```
struct tree *head = NULL;
head = push(3, head);
```

but there may still be other problems.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but why is the code output false when bst is passed?

Comment: Is that after you made this change? I can't tell unless I examine with a debugger, which is the suggested approach for you.

Comment: yes it is after the changes if possible use debugger